# Elasticsearch read model sync with write model

Tags: elasticsearch, synchronization, cqrs

My application following CQRS strategy separates Read model from Write model. I have a Product and multiple Purchase orders related to that Product.

The PurchaseOrder read model is in Elasticsearch and with product name attached. Now if I change the product name in the write model then I need to update all the PurchaseOrder's productName field accordingly in the read model(using Elasticsearch's bulk update API).

My question is: As I have millions of PurchaseOrders, will this productName sync be a performance issue? Or any suggestions for modeling such kind of syncing?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not believe that changing a product name on existing orders is a good idea (the invoice might have been generated and the product name in the order should match the one in the invoice), the question still has merit.

You may want your `PurchaseOrder` to only keep the `ID` (and perhaps the `version`?) of the `Product`, so that you can avoid such a mass update. This approach, on the other hand, requires a call to the `Product` aggregate root every time you want to translate the ID of the product in its own name. The impact of such a read can obviously be mitigated by using a cache.

I guess it really depend on the number of occurrences of such two circumstances to happen and I would then optimize the most occurring one.